# Any applications that need fast insert or delete for quadtrees?

Tags: data-structures, computer-vision, computer-games

I know that quadtree could be used in collision detection. But most articles I found are related with quadtree construction and retrieval. I wonder if there are some circumstances which involve both a great number of insert and remove operations? If any, please list out the papers.

I am planning to develop the quadtree structure which supports fast insertion and deletion. I am wondering whether there are applications that need this feature.

Comment: What's your motivation for asking?  What research have you done?

Comment: @D.W. I am planning to develop the quadtree structure which supports fast insertion and deletion, while I do not know whether there are applications which need it.

Comment: OK.  What research have you done?  Have you started by investigating whether any of the applications listed in [Wikipedia's list of common uses of quadtrees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree#Some_common_uses_of_quadtrees) needs fast insertion/deletion?  That seems like a basic starting point that you should explore before asking here.  We expect you to do a significant amount of research before asking, and to show us in the question what research you've done.  See https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Incidentally, I believe the standard algorithm is already fast ($O(\lg n)$ under some reasonable assumptions about "balance"), so there are limits to how much faster it could be.  You might already be aware of this.

Comment: @D.W. Thanks! Sorry that I have not noticed the guide yet.